# Python pickle load trained model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

I'm trying to apply a loaded trained model onto a new dataset. I pickle and unpickle the model:

```
classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = 'entropy', random_state = 0)
classifier = classifier.fit(features, classes)

saved_pickle_file = open('saved_model.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(classifier, saved_pickle_file)
saved_pickle_file.close()

load_pickle_file = open('saved_model.pkl', 'rb')
loaded_model = pickle.load(load_pickle_file)
```

But when I apply the loaded model to a new dataset, it produces this error:

```
loaded_model.predict(new_dataset)

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

Any reason as to why this is happening?

Comment: Can you show a [complete reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What do you see if you `print(loaded_model)` after un-pickling it?

Comment: @G.Anderson Hi! Printing loaded model gives: DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='entropy', max_depth=None,
            max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=0,
            splitter='best')

Comment: And are you able to access the attributes of the model, like `loaded_model.feature_importances_`?

Comment: @G.Anderson erm, no. I get errors such as: AttributeError: 'DecisionTreeClassifier' object has no attribute 'feature_importances'

Comment: At least it recognized it as a decisiontreeclassifier. Did you include the trailing underscore at the end for `feature_importances_`? If so, what about accessing `loaded_model.classes_`?

Comment: @G.Anderson I was about to say, I had forgotten the underscore! My bad. Yeah, I see a a numpy.ndarray of some features.

Comment: Unfortunately, if it sees the classifier as the proper object to access it's attributes but not it's methods, this may be beyond what (I at least) can assist with. I would try a few things: `close()` the file, or use a `with...` context manager, to ensure that the file open isn't still somehow holding the object hostage; try `copy()`ing 
 or deep copying the object as a completely new object; alternatively, provide more of your code as @VivekKumar suggested so we can see more of what's going on